# Using Google Analytics from a .NET desktop application

Tags: wpf, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is it possible to send "PageViews" and record activity using the official Google API for C#? for instance, if i want to track page views for my wpf/winforms desktop app. ?

Where can i find some oficial examples?

Comment: yes it is possible..is there any particular thing you are having issues with?

Comment: YES, i couldn't find any google-oficial examples of using their API to record User Session activity in .NET desktop application... i would appreciate it  if anyone could provide me with a link / example.

Comment: Whattt why did you -1 the question?? i saw tons of people looking for a way to do it using the official google API. they all ended up using GA.NET or another third party library! i want to use the oficial reporting core api but they only provide data query examples rather than data entry...

Comment: I also needed help in it.I wnated to use google analytics Core reporting API v3.There isn't any .net sample there.
this It shouldn't be voted negative

Comment: I were able to do queries and get data via v3 of API. I even converted some java code into .net for this. But in the end it is working all fine

Comment: AFAIK The `Core Reporting API` is for getting data **OUT** of Google Analytics and not for data insertions.

Comment: @KamranShahid full source code samples about it ?

Comment: long time Kiquenet on those api's

Answer (score 7):

I've just downloaded "Garlic" and tried the sample app and it works a treat!

https://github.com/dustyburwell/garlic

Comment: Do you know if it can be used to track individual users?

Answer (score 7):

**Disclaimer: I am the author for Gappalytics**

I think one missing here is [Gappalytics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Gappalytics/) for code/UI event tracking, it is a very simple library which unlocks you a full potential of Google analytics.

It works better than mentioned before lib's because it can persist uniqueness of a user this way your data will not be skewed.

Comment: I just tried it with a WPF app & I can confirm it works.

Comment: Gappalytics lacks documentation and source code not available on Github. Using Garlic instead.

Comment: Source code and cods are available in GitHub: https://github.com/Vasiliauskas/Gappalytics

Comment: This is absolutely awesome. Took me less than a minute to integrate and its working. All you need is a domain and a google tag id and you are good to go.

Answer (score 5):

Google just released the [Windows SDK](https://github.com/dotnet/windows-sdk-for-google-analytics) for Google Analytics. It works with UWP, Xamarin, <del>Windows Forms, and WPF</del>.

The official [announcement](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/02/08/windows-developer-day-creators-update/#o0Qr5wLkfGs4jh5H.97) was made at the most recent Windows Developer Day on Feb 8th, 2017.

Comment: I couldn't find the nuget for WPF .net 4.5

Comment: @JobaDiniz good to see you here! I'm Matthew Bordas on [this](https://github.com/dotnet/windows-sdk-for-google-analytics/issues/16) issue in the repo haha. I edited my answer to accurately reflect the library's lack of WinForm and WPF support, thanks for the comment.

Comment: 2 years ago, without updates about Windows SDK for Google Analytics.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some options, none perfect though. Google has an iOS and android SDK. Why not a Windows SDK???

- [Garlic](https://github.com/dustyburwell/garlic)
- [Ga.net](https://github.com/pavels/Ga.net)
- [Server Side Google Analytics](http://blog.diniscruz.com/2013/01/creating-server-side-google-analytics.html)