# Submitting Data to Google Analytics from WPF

Tags: wpf, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to send data to Google Analytics from a WPF application.  I can't find any resource online which clearly defines how to do that.  I know that there are numerous NuGet packages available, but I'm not sure which to use, nor how to implement them.  I also know that there are some third-party "helper" libraries available (see [Using Google Analytics from a .NET desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16217894/1378356)), which I'm not interested in.  It also looks like most instructions online are showing how to "pull" data from GA, not how to push.  Not looking for "maybe"'s or workarounds but what the normal straightforward way to do this is.  This shouldn't be complicated.  Just need a "Hello World".

Can you please point me in the right direction?  Thanks,

Comment: You should look into [Measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/). It allows you to send data to Google Analytics through a simple HTTP request, regardless of what language you are using it is bound to have an http request library. See the [hit builder tool](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/) to see how to verify the request.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google-analytics.com/collect");
        request.Method = "POST";

        // the request body we want to send
        var postData = new Dictionary<string, string>
                   {
                       { "v", "1" }, //analytics protocol version
                       { "tid", "UA-XXXXXXXX-X" }, //analytics tracking property id
                       { "cid", "XXXX"}, //unique user identifier
                       { "t", "event" }, //event type
                       { "ec", category },
                       { "ea", action },
                   };

        var postDataString = postData
            .Aggregate("", (data, next) => string.Format("{0}&{1}={2}", data, next.Key,
                                                         Uri.EscapeDataString(next.Value)))
            .TrimEnd('&');

        // set the Content-Length header to the correct value
        request.ContentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(postDataString);

        // write the request body to the request
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            writer.Write(postDataString);
        }

        var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (webResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Google Analytics tracking did not return OK 200. Returned: {webResponse.StatusCode}");
        }
```